# why plugin is not initializing dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#" + IdToInitialize).cycle("destroy").cycle({
    fx: $("#cyclescroll").val(),
    easing: $("#cyclebounce").val(),
    speed: 1000,
    timeout: 2000
});
```

Whats the problem here , why cycle plugin is not initializing again with new settings?

Comment: what values are you getting for each settings ? You call twice times `cycel` instead one

Comment: What happens? What  do you expect? Which plugin is this? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Cycle plugin is already running on ($("#" + IdToInitialize)) now i want that when user provides new setting to plugin and add new images dynamically in the slideshow container so it will reinitialize accordingly ( so for this i am destroying the old one and initializing the new)

Comment: haye you placed this code in $(document).ready() function

Comment: no, i placed it in the function, so when user click "done" button, it executes

Comment: What is returned by these two `$("#cyclescroll").val()`, `$("#cyclebounce").val()`?

Comment: string for scrolling image in left right up down direction and InBounce etc effects while scrolling .These value have no effect over this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
$("#" + IdToInitialize).cycle("destroy");
$("#" + IdToInitialize).cycle({
    fx: $("#cyclescroll").val(),
    easing: $("#cyclebounce").val(),
    speed: 1000,
    timeout: 2000 
});
```

Make sure

`$("#cyclescroll").val()` should return the values as  `fade, scrollUp, shuffle`
`$("#cyclebounce").val()` should return the values as  `easeInOutBack, easeOutBack`

Refer **[Cycle Options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)**

Answer (score 0):

One of the values you are using to reinitialize your plugin is incorrect.  Eitehr IdToInitialize, fx, or easing are not correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/ny2Tj/3/

The following works as expected when clicking on the button:

```
<div id="sliders">
<div id="slideshow">
<img src="http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/upload/2012/04/why_should_there_be_dark_matte/AS17-148-22727_lrg-thumb-500x500-74032.jpeg" />
<img src="http://weblogs.marylandweather.com/4526619322_1912218db8.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.silverstar-academy.com/Blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/03-14-12N00184967.jpg" />
<img src="http://cdn.the2012scenario.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/sunspot-500x500.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="pager"></div>
</div>

<button id="reinit">Reinit</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({fx:'scrollHorz', pager: '#pager'});
$('#reinit').click(function() {
$('#slideshow').cycle('destroy').cycle({fx:'scrollVert'}); // change effect remove pager    
});
```